# Kodi custom build : unable to create application

Tags: windows, skin, xbmc, kodi, custom-build

I have prepared xbmc-Krypton build with custom skin and applied necessary changes as below :

```
At : <XBMC_SRC>\system\settings\settings.xml
    CHANGE SKIN NAME
        <default>my skin name</default>

At : <XBMC_SRC>\system\addon-manifest.xml
    ADD SKIN NAME
        i.e. add entry of skin <addon>my skin name</addon>

At : <XBMC_SRC>\Makefile.in
    COMMENT block - skin textures
        i.e.
            # skin textures
            ifeq (@USE_TEXTUREPACKER@,1)
            skins: @TEXTUREPACKER@
               $(MAKE) -C $(ESTUARY_MEDIA)
               $(MAKE) -C $(ESTOUCHY_MEDIA)
            else
            skins:
            endif
```

now package is installed but when I run package I got error message shown in snapshot.[image]

System details:
OS: Windows 10 64 bit
kodi version - 17 (Krypton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by manually copy skin add on and its dependencies at `E:\xbmc-Krypton\kodi-build\addons`